# Web page with Skrollr JS not working on mobile browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, skrollr

I'm creating a web page with some scrolling effects. Here I used skrollr plugin. But, I'm having some problems on mobile browsers. Specially on chorme.

The web page works great on desktop browsers but the page is not scrollable at all on mobile browsers.

Visit this link on a mobile chrome browser : 
http://www.geniusamigos.com/mystuff/vr3/4.html

Is this a common problem or it's just me ?

Thanks...